# ExecutorSubscribableChannel[clientInboundChannel] Access Denied

Tags: jhipster

Does anyone know how to fix this in latest jhipster 3.5.1?

I found some old bug reports about this but they're all marked resolved.  I'm not doing anything custom.  I have a gateway, uaa, and single microservice.  I enabled websockets on the gateway.  Any time I refresh the page on the gateway I get this error.

```
2016-08-10 12:10:13.208 ERROR 14932 --- [io-8080-exec-10] w.s.h.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator : Unhandled error for ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator [delegate=LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator [delegate=SubProtocolWebSocketHandler[StompSubProtocolHandler[v10.stomp, v11.stomp, v12.stomp]]]]

org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Failed to send message to ExecutorSubscribableChannel[clientInboundChannel]; nested exception is org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
        at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:127)
        at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler.afterSessionEnded(StompSubProtocolHandler.java:595)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.clearSession(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.afterConnectionClosed(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:368)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecorator.afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.afterConnectionClosed(LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:72)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.afterConnectionClosed(ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:78)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.delegateConnectionClosed(AbstractSockJsSession.java:430)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.SockJsWebSocketHandler.afterConnectionClosed(SockJsWebSocketHandler.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.onClose(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:141)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.fireEndpointOnClose(WsSession.java:542)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.onClose(WsSession.java:524)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processDataControl(WsFrameBase.java:348)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processData(WsFrameBase.java:290)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInputBuffer(WsFrameBase.java:131)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:71)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler$WsReadListener.onDataAvailable(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:185)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletInputStream.onDataAvailable(AbstractServletInputStream.java:198)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractProcessor.upgradeDispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:96)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:647)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
        at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
        at org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.ChannelSecurityInterceptor.preSend(ChannelSecurityInterceptor.java:69)
        at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorChain.applyPreSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:158)
        at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:113)
        ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug ([just fixed](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/3971)) affecting the combination of UAA and Websockets.  Here are the steps to fix it on a generated app.

1. Inject AuthServerProvider into JhiTrackerService

`JhiTrackerService.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$window', '$cookies', '$http', '$q', 'AuthServerProvider'];
    function JhiTrackerService ($rootScope, $window, $cookies, $http, $q, AuthServerProvider) {`

2. After you set the `url` variable, but before you set the `socket` variable, add the access_token to the URL (add the lines with a plus sign)

`var url = '//' + loc.host + loc.pathname + 'websocket/tracker';
+ var authToken = AuthServerProvider.getToken();
+ if(authToken){
+         url += '?access_token=' + authToken;
+ }
var socket = new SockJS(url);`

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick turnaround and bug fix for this Jon.